# Searching for an element in an array and returning it

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

The following method always returns NULL:

```
public SalesItem findItem(String itemCode){

        // to be implemented
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        SalesItem[] item;
        item = new SalesItem[1];
        item[0] = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < size -1; i++) {
          if (itemCode.equals(items[i].getItemCode())) {
            item[0] = items[i];
            System.out.println("Item - " + item +" is added to the shopping cart.");
            cart.addItem(items[i]);
          }

          else {
            item[0] = null;
          }
        }
        return item[0];
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

If the last item your for loops check doesn't match the item then you set `item[0]` to null.

Then you return `item[0]`.

So the for loop is pointless. You should probably return the item as it is found.

Comment: And how do I do that...? :/

Comment: @Kimmm inside the if you could do `return item[i];`

Answer (score 1):

You have do that 
item[0]=null
and you are comparing itemCode to item[0] which is equla to null that's why it is always returns null.